# Android studio does not compile classes.dex into apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, apk, dex

Every time I try to run my app on an emulator or device, installation fails with an `INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT` error. Examining LogCat and the apk spit out by Android Studio reveals that the apk does not contain any classes.dex file.

Strangely, compiling the project from the command line works properly, and will even get android studio to work for a few builds (although the resulting apk does not work completely).

I have tried EVERYTHING TO GET THIS ERROR TO STOP. Reinstalling AS, reinstalling the SDK, reinstalling the JDK, restarting my PC, recreating projects, nothing helps. This error just won't go away. I really want to be able to use Android Studio and get away from Eclipse, but Google is making that really hard.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you should add the gradle command you used. I would guess it doesn't match the build variant that is set in Android Studio.